# Add a class to a panels pane

Tags: theming, panels

Is it possible to add a class to single pane (like the left side) on a panels page? I'm using a grid based theme and it would be nice if i can just add things like 'grid-5 alpha' to a certain pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Panels UI, every Pane has a little cog. Click it, and menu appears. There is an entry called "CSS Settings". There you can add per pane classes.